# Can not assign value to an IN OUT parameter

Tags: oracle, plsql

```
procedure check_startDate_is_grower_than_last_foo(startDate IN OUT DATE) as
    last_foo_tsp DATE;
begin
    select max(version_tsp) into last_foo_tsp from foo;
    if startDate <= last_foo_tsp then
        if trunc(startDate) = trunc(last_foo_tsp) then
            startDate := (last_foo_tsp + 1/86400); -- +1 seg                
        else
            raise_application_error(-20001, 'Blabla');
        end if;
    end if;
end;
```

I get an error:

```
PLS-00363: expression 'STARTDATE' cannot be used as an assignment target
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you did wrong, because - it works for me.

```
SQL> alter session set nls_date_format = 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss';

Session altered.

SQL> select * from foo;

VERSION_TSP
-------------------
15.02.2022 00:00:00
```

---

```
SQL> create or replace
  2  procedure p_check (startDate IN OUT DATE) as
  3      last_foo_tsp DATE;
  4  begin
  5      select max(version_tsp) into last_foo_tsp from foo;
  6      if startDate <= last_foo_tsp then
  7          if trunc(startDate) = trunc(last_foo_tsp) then
  8              startDate := (last_foo_tsp + 1/86400); -- +1 seg
  9          else
 10              raise_application_error(-20001, 'Blabla');
 11          end if;
 12      end if;
 13  end;
 14  /

Procedure created.
```

Testing:

```
SQL> set serveroutput on
SQL> declare
  2    l_datum date := date '2022-02-15';
  3  begin
  4    p_check (l_datum);
  5    dbms_output.put_line('result = ' || l_datum);
  6  end;
  7  /
result = 15.02.2022 00:00:01

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Comment: I found it. I thought the error was in my procedure but it's from where I call it (another procedure). I have to declare the variable I'm passing also as IN OUT. Which looks strange to me having to do that but anyway

Comment: That's what demo in "Testing" shows.